# Ignore Dependency Conflict in requirements.txt file - Pip 24.0

Tags: pip

I get the following error when I install the requirements

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 265), -r requirements.txt (line 56) and sqlparse==0.4.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested sqlparse==0.4.1
    django 3.2 depends on sqlparse>=0.2.2
    djongo 1.3.6 depends on sqlparse==0.2.4

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I want to ignore and not install dependencies of Djongo

My requirements.txt has the following

```
Django==3.2
sqlparse==0.4.1
djongo==1.3.6 --config-setting="--build-option=--no-deps"
```

I also tried

```
djongo==1.3.6 --config-setting="--install-option=--no-deps"
```

But these do not seem to work.
How can I overcome this issue?